# asp.net async treeview

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I am trying to build a dynamic treeview which is populated when the user clicks on one of the pluses. on my database I have records which work like parent and child, so a record has link to its parent record and link to all its child records (I think the way the database works is not relevant so im not going to explain). The issue is some of the records may have upto 1000000 child records and as you can see loading all of them at once can cause some issues as you may be loading millions of nodes at once.

so I was wondering if any one had some goof tutorials on treeviews.

Comment: An inital concern, how are you expecting to present 1,000,000 child records in any kind of accessible way? The pattern you are looking for is lazy loading.

Comment: LOL I might have been a bit over the top with the million child records, but i can see where you coming from when displaying that many records.

Answer (score 3):

1 - Set the `TreeView.ExpandDepth` to `0`. This eliminates the expansion of the added TreeNode objects in the TreeView and shows the expansion symbol [+] next to each TreeNode that has the TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand property set to true.

2- Set the `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` to `True` for each branch TreeNode. When the `TreeNode.ChildNodes` collection is empty, the expansion symbol [+] will be showed only next to TreeNode objects that has `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` property set to `true`.

3- Handle the `TreeView.TreeNodePopulate` event to poulate branch nodes on expansion. This event will be fired when a TreeNode - with the `TreeNode.PopulateOnDemand` set to `true` - has been expanded right before the TreeView.TreeNodeExpanded event gets fired.

Comment: I want to do something similar to this ... but i dont wnat to use any third party stuff ... i actually want to create this myself.